# Eclipse Juno/MyLyn does not show change sets in synchronization view

Tags: eclipse, egit, mylyn

I'm new to MyLyn and I really want to use the change sets automatic management function. So what I did is I shared a project via git, then create a new task, activate it, made some changes, open synchronize view and synchronize. Now I should be able to see my change sets, right? But the dropdown button that suppose allow me to choose the Change Sets mode only shows "All Model", "Workspace", "Java Workspace", "Git commits". There is no "Change Sets" option.

BTW, I did toggle Change Sets in Synchronization Preference/Models. So what did I miss here? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try using *Team->Synchronize Workspace* from the context menu of a project, which is easier to make sure you really show the changes.

If that does not lead to any differences, you might be missing the Mylyn connector for git. Mylyn itself does the tracking of your activities, but to work with egit (or subversion, or...) you also need to install the "Mylyn versions connector: git" and probably "Mylyn context connector: Team support".

The Mylyn (Juno) update site is http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/juno.

Comment: Solved, it turns out that I did not install Mylyn context connector: Team support. Thank you!