# Eclipse Git Synchronize does not display changes

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, synchronize

No matter what I do, Eclipse (EGit) doesn't display the changes. I've searched a lot for this issue, but cannot solve it. A friend of mine has the same issue. In the past everything worked fine, but from one day to the other the issue occured.

When I hit *Team > Synchronize Workspace*, only the dialog "**Synchronizing Git: No changes found.**" appears. When I choose *Team > Advanced > Synchronize*, the same happens.

I also installed a new Eclipse (with a fresh Windows) and issue was still there. With my Ubuntu notebook everything is fine.

Does anybody have the same issue? Is there a solution? I also tried to install the plugins mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291834/eclipse-juno-mylyn-does-not-show-change-sets-in-synchronization-view), but it didn't work for me.

**Update**
Eclipse also displays incoming changes (after fetching from upstream) and the changed files (with an arrow), but the synchronize view still doesn't show the changes.

**Update 2** I've tested a project from Github and there everything works as apected. What could be the difference between these two projects? I've checked the repository settings and they are equal. Could the authentication cause the issues? Like I've said, the project works fine on my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Is it possible that one of the projects is closed or not imported into Eclipse? What changed when this suddenly started happening, did you upgrade anything or change something in the project configuration?

Comment: Nothing changed. Like I've said, I also installed a complete new OS and a fresh Eclipse. After that I pulled the project with EGit and the error was already there. On my Ubuntu machine everything is running fine.

Comment: I've added another update.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used to have the same problem but upgrading to EGit 2.2 seems to have taken care of it. Things are now consistent between "git status" at command line and "Team / Synchronize Workspace" in Eclipse.

You can get EGit from [here](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egit-git-team-provider#.UQf94B3m2_3) or you can add the update site http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-2.2 to Eclipse.

**Latest Egit Update Site:**
http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

Comment: I had never seen this bug before, and then experienced it in Juno after my first time using the option to commit-and-push all in one step.  Upgrading to the latest EGit fixed the issue.

Comment: The default Juno update site currently has EGit 2.1, and Dan's helpful answer gives an update site for 2.2.  However, EGit is now already at 2.3 and changing pretty frequently.  The easiest thing to do is just use the Eclipse Marketplace, which always points to the latest version.

Answer (score 16):

I've tried the new EGit, re-cloning the project and nothing worked except this:

1. In the Synchronize view, click on the dropdown arrow next to Synchronize button, then select "Synchronize...".
2. In the dialog that appears choose Git, press Next.
3. Then the crucial part - select destination to be HEAD for your repository and check "Include local uncommitted changes in comparison".
4. Click Finish.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you!  That "Destination" widget was rather clunky for me.  Had to click it a few times before it finally showed the drop down list.

Answer (score 2):

[Staged Changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ3kc.png)This has worked for me :

Whenever you made any changes. Right click on your Project name then Go to Team and click on  "Add to Index". Now again Right click on your Project Name then Go to Team and click on "Commit". Now You will see that Git Staging console has been opened and the changes you have made are started displaying in Staged Changes box.

Answer (score 1):

Before you can synchronize your workspace, you need to do a "fetch" from the remote repository (`Team -> Fetch from Upstream`) to get all the incoming changes into your local repository. Afterwards you can synchronize them.

If you don't want to make two clicks for synchronizing, you can enable "Always launch fetch before synchronisation" in `Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Synchronize`.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this was already checked. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

We were strugeling with the same problem. It turned out that we had to remove all options in Git->Synchronize preferences.

We are using Eclipse Juno and Kepler. Removing the options solved the problem for both.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, I ran into the same problem.

During synchronization, in repository selection, the option **Include local uncommitted changes in comparison** is not checked and shows **No changes found** in the **Synchronize** view. Synchronizing with that option checked, shown the changes.

Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) - MacOS