# No Mylyn change sets in team>synchronize view (JIRA connector, Kepler, egit)

Tags: eclipse, jira, egit, mylyn

This appears similar to [Eclipse Juno/MyLyn does not show change sets in synchronization view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291834/eclipse-juno-mylyn-does-not-show-change-sets-in-synchronization-view), but the answer to that doesn't seem to apply to me, and I can't find any other relevant hits from google or here

I have Kepler and the following installed:

- Eclipse GIT (3.0.3...)
- Mylyn Context Connector: Team Support (3.9.1....)
- Mylyn Versions Connector: Git (1.1.1...)
- Task focused interface for Eclipse Git Team Provider (3.0.3..)
- Atlassian Connector for Eclipse (3.0.8...)
- (+ the default Mylyn stuff at 3.9.1...)

In team>synchronize I have all models enabled (including change sets)

I connect to JIRA happily and can activate tasks, attach files to context etc (ie Mylyn seems to work fine)

Egit also works fine standalone (connecting to bitbucket).

I followed the instructions here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/User_Guide#Task-focused_Change_Sets

But in the synchronize view/perspective. I never have a change set option available.

(eg activate task, add some files to context, modify them, they show as "modified")

The other models seem to work fine (eg I can select a project, synchronize, view incoming/outgoing changes)

Anyone have any ideas?

I initially tried with the default Mylyn/egit/Atlassian installs, then added the Mylyn Team/Git connectors, then (desperation) added the egit task focused interface ... is there any possibility it's related to order of install?!

Or does it not work properly with JIRA for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, the mylyn forum claims that change sets aren't supported for egit: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1148769/#msg_1148769

I'll accept that as fact in spite of Clemens' suggestion that it will work (which I assume is an SVN-specific answer?) and update if I hear back from him.

Update: location of Egit/Mylyn issue, in case other people want to weigh in: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=413507

On reflection, it's not a critical piece of functionality since if you use feature branches then the concept of a change set is somewhat redundant anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened for me. I installed the Mylyn context connector for Java development and the Subversive SVN integration for the Mylyn project and now it's working.

Comment: Hmm, looked promising since I didn't have the subversive integration installed, but still doesn't work. I have "Subversive SVN integration for the Mylyn project (optional)" and all the Mylyn features and integrations from their download.eclipse site except subclipse (which refused to install since i don't have subclipse installed). Do you have subclipse installed also? And to double check, you are able to see egit change sets? Thanks for the response, I'll trying installing subclipse + Mylyn integration in case that's it.